# Send Object from one template to another via iron router, meteor

Tags: meteor, routes, iron-router

I am getting some data on a template via meteor.call. Now I want to send the object to another template. I am using iron:router for routing. Below is my code :

```
Meteor.call(functionName, function(err, res){
    if(!err){
      //do something
      Router.go('templateName', {
        data : res
      });
    } 
});


Router.route('/url/:data?', function(){
    console.log(this.params.data);
})
```

In the console.log, I am getting the object as string. Data returned is

```
"object Object"        => (this is a string, not an object)
```

I don't want to use Session variables as they are global. I am confused as to how to send data from one template to another. 
The templates are not related to each other (parent-child relation) and hence I can't use `{{>templateName data=this}}`

I also tried using query parameters as suggested by @Jankapunkt

```
Router.go('templateName', {},{
    query : res
});

Router.route('/url/:data?', function(){
    console.log(JSON.stringify(this.params.query));
});
```

Printed statement :

```
{"0":"[object Object]","1":"[object Object]","2":"[object Object]","3":"[object Object]","4":"[object Object]","5":"[object Object]","6":"[object Object]","7":"[object Object]","8":"[object Object]","9":"[object Object]","10":"[object Object]","11":"[object Object]","12":"[object Object]","13":"[object Object]","14":"[object Object]"}
```

Any idea on how to proceed?

Comment: Would it be a problem to pass the data as [query parameters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string)?

Comment: Your route should be `'/url/:data` not `/url/:data?`

Comment: @MichelFloyd Isn't '?' just to say that the field is optional. I using /:data instead of /:data? but the result is same.

Comment: @JankapunktI tried using query parameters too but the result is same. Edited the question more info. I know I am missing something very basic but can't figure out what

Comment: What is the exact url you are testing?

Comment: I also see nothing in the [iron router docs](http://iron-meteor.github.io/iron-router/) that use a ? to make a parameter optional, where did you get that idea?